# Does RMI guarantee the order of execution?

Tags: java, rmi, rpc

For example, when one client executes something like this:

```
serverQueue.push(X);
serverQueue.push(Y);
Object Z = serverQueue.front();
boolean orderPreserved = Z.equals(X);
```

Assuming only one client and that `serverQueue` is an ordinary queue, is it guaranteed that `orderPreserved` will always be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does RMI guarantee the order of execution?

In the sense that you mean yes.

If thread T makes or attempts to make 2 RMI calls sequentially in a given order to remote object R, then it is guaranteed that R will get those calls sequentially in that same order.

```
serverQueue.push(X);
serverQueue.push(Y);
Object Z = serverQueue.front();
```

The semantics of Java method call means that the local (proxy) method calls occur in the source code order.  That means that locally the second `push` doesn't start until the first `push` returns.

Now the synchronous nature of RMI means that the local proxy `push` calls do not return until the response from the remote object comes back.  The call on the proxy waits for the response from the remote method call; i.e. either a normal return response (without any value in this case) or an exception response.

So if you put this all together, you can prove that the 2 `push` calls on the remote object corresponding to the proxy `serverQueue` must occur in the same order as the local calls, and that they cannot overlap.

All you need to establish this is the facts that Java will not reorder sequential events within a thread, and that RMI is synchronous.  The rest follows from simple logic, without the need to consider / resort to the details of the RMI implementation.

---

Now obviously, if the two `push` calls were made on different threads, there is NO guarantee that they will be processed in order by the remote object.  But that is a different situation to this one.

Comment: +1 but if the calls are made on different threads there is really no order to guarantee.

Answer (score 4):

Since RMI is synchronous, the operations will be executed in the same order they're called.

In other words, if the operations give orderPreserved=true when executed locally, they'll give the same result over RMI.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any credible source?

Comment: @mghareeb - Someone with 50k+ rep is probably a credible source.  Plus, this follows logically from the definition of synchronous.

Comment: @StephenC The thing is I'm currently in argument about this bit. I wanted a source that explains exactly what RMI provides and what it does not.

For example, if connection is lost before the first push but is then continued for the second push, will `orderPreserved` still be true? Is this necessarily implied from the term synchronous? Thanks!

Comment: @mghareeb - yes, and yes.  You can work it our from first principles.

Answer (score 2):

> Does RMI guarantee the order of execution?

RMI doesn't have to guarantee it. Java guarantees it. You can't reach the second method call until the first one has returned. RMI method semantics are identical to local method semantics, with the exception of the parameter passing mode.